# Highlighting JS syntax with ngx-prism

Tags: javascript, angular, prismjs

I want to display some code at my site and highlight syntax so it's more readable. I basically wanted to use some library for that so I found this ngx-prism. I followed every step from [its docs](https://github.com/ngx-prism/core#usage) which is:

I run both commands:

- `npm i --save @ngx-prism/core`
- `npm i --save @types/prismjs@1.9.0 prismjs@1.9.0`

I imported PrismModule to my app.module and added it to imports array

```
import { PrismModule } from '@ngx-prism/core';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PrismModule
],
```

Then in one of my components I tried to use it:

```
<ngx-prism [language]="'javascript'">
     {{ "var lol = 'wtf'; \n alert(lol) " }}
</ngx-prism>
```

I don't have any error but highlighting doesn't work.. It looks like bare `<code>` tag:

[image]

I build my project with `ng serve --aot`.

Am I doing something wrong or this lib is broken? If that's the case then can you share me some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included one of the theme CSS files? Without that it won't know which style to use to highlight.

In your `styles.css` file, include a line like so:

`@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css';`

Check the docs for the full list of available themes (you only need one):

```
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-coy.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-dark.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-funky.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism-twilight.css';
@import '~prismjs/themes/prism.css';
```

Comment: I am having same problem with JSON. I have imported css in my global.scss as well. any idea what else could be wrong. 

https://github.com/ngx-prism/core/issues/13